# What is the name of this seed/fruit?

Tags: identification, shrubs, fruits

What is the name of the seed/fruit in this image? It was obtained from a bush.

[image: Fruit, next to a 1 Euro coin and measure for comparison.]

Comment: Can you add more information on where you found the berry, a picture of the bush, etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately they brought this to me so I dont have a picture,but it is from a bush for sure.

Comment: Cotoneaster? How big is this shrub?

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without more detail.